# How to rename existing Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app, but now I want to rename existing logic app in Microsoft Azure portal.

I have been looking for options, but could not find one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot rename web app as far as I'm aware. You can redeploy using different name and then delete existing one.

Comment: I don't have a link to back that up, but I'm pretty sure it can't be done, so I second that.

Comment: Just like any resource  in Azure, you cannot rename them.

Comment: Almost any :( SQL databases can be renamed.

Comment: You can clone the logic app and set the new name, then you could delete the older one

Comment: The question is about logic apps not web apps. But yes, logic apps can't be renamed either.

Answer (score 20):

Select the LogicApp, clone it with a new name, delete the old one.

Comment: Also, you can create a blank LogicApp and then copy the code from the source one... Just be careful with API connections.

Answer (score 2):

Existing logic app cannot be renamed. we can clone the existing logic app with a new name.
However,the cloned logic app will be created in the same resource group of the existing logic app. we can change the resource group or location of the logic app once the cloning is completed, but in order to avoid any run time error we need to update the subscription/Resource group name or id in the code view.

Comment: Please add a source confirming your statement.

Comment: You can create a blank LogicApp and then copy the code from the source one... Just be careful with API connections.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename Logic App... however you can redeploy it in minutes using PowerShell

If you just want workflow definition then

```powershell
$rg = "my-resoruce-group"
$logicAppName = "my-logic-app"
$newName = "my-new-name"

$logicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $logicAppName
New-AzLogicApp `
    -ResourceGroupName $rg `
    -Name "New-Name" `
    -Definition $logicApp.Definition `
    -Location $logicApp.Location
```

Or export entire resource as ARM template and reploy it either via PowerShell, CLI or through portal

```powershell
$rg = "my-resoruce-group"
$logicAppName = "my-logic-app"
$logicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $logicAppName

Export-AzResourceGroup `
    -ResourceGroupName $rg `
    -Resource $logicApp.Id `
    -Path "arm.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

One cannot able to rename the logic app , you can able to clone the logic app with the option available in overview section of logic app as available in below picture and provide the new name. Once the new logic app gets created we can delete the old logic app.
[image: Clone option in overview section of logic app]

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the Azure Resources naming can't be renamed. However If you tend to follow Proper Sequences you can have your Cloud Infrastructure better Managed.
Make Use of Azure Deployment Methods to Tweak Configurations Manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Renaming logic app is not supported by using azure portal.
You can use below methods

1. Create clone with new name and delete existing one(only supported for consumption)
2. Deploy logic app with new name and delete existing one (Support consumption + standard)

Comment: What does this add that’s not already stated in previous answers?

Comment: @JeremyCaney previous answers didn't covered standard logic app, only focused on consumption.